# How did Jimmy retrieve Clyde's arm?

Tags: plot-explanation, logan-lucky

In *Logan Lucky* Clyde's prosthetic arm was sucked by the machine into the vault.

**How did Jimmy retrieve it?**

The machine couldn't suck it back, an arm isn't that light, and Jimmy couldn't just walk inside the vault.

Did I miss something?

Comment: Wasn't the arm just trapped in that machine somewhere? Did it actually go into the vault?

Comment: @BrettFromLA I got the feeling it was, they felt the pipes and all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At 1:48:40, the movie clearly shows Jimmy opening up the machine and taking out the prosthetic arm, and putting it in a garbage bag.